# Remove Everything in the RAM

Tags: linux, linux-mint, arch-linux, linux-kernel, kali-linux

Is there a command in Linux that removes everything that is loaded in the RAM including the kernel itself while the OS is up and running?

Comment: The kernel is the heart of the operating system.  See [WikiPedia: Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)).  Removing it would render your OS unusable. What exactly is going on that makes you think you need to remove the kernel?  Update your question with more information,

Comment: it is the `shutdown` command .... the computer cannot run without any program in memory

Comment: @jsotola you should make that an answer.

Comment: I do know anything better than pulling the power cord or taking out the battery

Comment: My professor has asked us a question in an assignment asking us to destroy the kernel so that the kernel malfunctions; therefore, the kernel will no longer provide service for the user. There is a command that you could run that would basically malfunction the kernel and freeze everything afterwards. After running the command and rebooting it (you have to reboot because nothing is responding), the OS won't load; as a result, you have destroyed the kernel. However, the key thing in my professor's question is that to write the command and destroy the kernel without rebooting it.

Comment: The command is as follows:
~$ sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
You can also check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh1XIHDl5NY if you still don't know what I mean @eyoung100
I thought that since the kernel loads itself up in the RAM when you start the OS and you have the kernel in the hardware, you can then write a command that would combine the command I mentioned with a command for deleting everything in the RAM so that the system can then and only then malfunction without rebooting.

Comment: @DanazSdiq That command when run as `root` does destroy a whole system by removing the entire directory structure, leaving you with an empty partition.  Note that this is overkill as `rm -vRf /boot` would also delete the kernel.  The way your question is phrased led me to believe that your kernel was malfunctioning in some way....

Answer (score 2):

There is `kexec` to load a different kernel.

If you just want to remove everything without replacing it, that doesn't make sense. If you remove the kernel (and everything else), then the OS won't continue to run. You could as well use `halt` or `poweroff`.

Comment: Thank you. The reason why I want this is that my professor has asked us a question in an assignment asking us to destroy the kernel so that the kernel malfunctions; therefore, the kernel will no longer provide service for the user. There is a command that you could run that would basically malfunction the kernel and freeze everything afterwards. Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh1XIHDl5NY
However, the key thing in my professor's question is that to write the command and destroy the kernel without rebooting it.
The command is
~$ sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root

Comment: I thought that since the kernel loads itself up in the RAM when you start the OS and you have the kernel in the hardware, you can then write a command that would combine the command I mentioned with a command for deleting everything in the RAM so that the system can then and only then malfunction without rebooting.
Any thought?